# simple combinatorics - where is my mistake

Tags: combinatorics

In the olympic games we want to organize 8 flags on 8 poles, 4 US flags, 2 french flags, 2 german flags.

We want to know how many combinations are there where a US flag is adjacent to a french flag.

Obviously the number of overall combinations is $\frac{8!}{4!2!2!} = 420$.

Now let's glue together an american flag and a french flag together. that gives us overall 7 flags. 3 america, 1 french, 2 german, 1 our new "flag block".

that's $\frac{7!}{3!1!2!1!} = 420$, but we need to double it since we have the internal combination of our block ("US France" or "France US"), so overall we have $2 \times 420 = 840$ combinations. But that makes no sense since overall we have $420$ combinations. where is the mistake

Comment: Some of your combinations contain the "new flag" more than once, you need to use inclusion/exclusion principle.

Comment: Your method counts American FrenchAmeri as different than AmeriFrench American  when they should be the same.  Likewise French AmeriFrench different fro FrenchAmeri French

Answer (score 1):

You’re overlooking the fact that most of the acceptable arrangements have more than one instance of a U.S. flag adjacent to a French flag, and you’re counting those arrangements more than once each. It’s easier to count the arrangements in which a U.S. and a French flag *aren’t* adjacent and then subtract from the total. The point is that each French flag must have either the end of the row, the other French flag, or a German flag on each side of it.

- We can put the two French flags together and surround them with the German flags.
- We can put the two French flags together at one end of the line with a German flag as ‘insulation’.
- We can put a French flag at one end, followed by a German flag, the other French flag, and the other German flag.

Anything else will result in a U.S. flag next to a French flag. It’s not too hard to work out the number of arrangements in each of these three cases.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Brian M. Scott's answer, here's a clear example to show your multiple counting:

Consider the arrangement:

USA France USA Germany USA Germany France USA

How many times does your model count this?

1: The USA France block is the first two flags.

2: The France USA block is the second and third flag.

3: The France USA block is the last two flags.

So you count this one configuration three times.

In particular, it multiply counts each arrangement once for each France-USA adjacency it contains.